# Setting up lintr with CI

Tags: r, r-markdown, circleci, github-actions, lintr

I've been unsucessfully trying to setup `lintr` package with GitHub actions (circleCi would be good too, since it's a private repo)  to check PR and pushes.

My project is a book so i don't need package build checks, but only enforcing style since there are serveral authors.

I've read this [readme](https://github.com/jimhester/lintr) and this [article](https://circleci.com/blog/increase-reliability-in-data-science-and-machine-learning-projects-with-circleci/) but i couldn't figure out **what should a .yml file look like is this case**.

Comment: Are you using circleci or github actions? You need to narrow your question to the specific one you are using or ask a specific question about either if it is your goal to use both

Comment: @smac89 Top choice is GitHub actions.

Comment: What you need now is a command line tool which can run lintr on your files. Do you know such a tool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured that out. Still need to cache `lintr` but at least it is working:

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master

name: lint

jobs:
  lint:
    runs-on: macOS-latest
    env:
      GITHUB_PAT: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-r@master

      - name: Install lintr
        run: install.packages("lintr")
        shell: Rscript {0}

      - name: Lint

        run: lintr::lint_dir(linters = lintr::with_defaults(assignment_linter = NULL, line_length_linter = NULL, spaces_left_parentheses_linter = NULL), pattern = '[.]R$|[.]Rmd')
        shell: Rscript {0}
```